# push new comments into comments array in mongoose/mongodb/angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been stuck for the last 3 days trying to push a new comment object into my array of comments using yo generated crud module.

Here is the server.model for my comments schema, which I am using as a subdocument:

```
var CommentsSchema = new Schema({

comment: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});
mongoose.model('Comments', CommentsSchema);
```

This is the task schema, where I include the comments schema :

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Task name',
    trim: true
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
//comments : [{
  //  text: { type: String },
//    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  //  user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
//}]
comments: [CommentsSchema]
});
mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

I can manually insert comments into a task using mongodb shell,  like so:

```
db.tasks.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5711856735e9cb1938845048")},{ $addToSet: { comments: { "comment" : "i am also a comment"  }  } } )
```

however I am struggling to set up the correct function to insert into the task on my client side using a function in js/angularjs.

I have set up a form to add a new comment with:

```
<form name="vm.form.taskForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="vm.newCo(vm.form.taskForm.$valid)" novalidate>    
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.task.comments.comment" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="ask a question about this task">
<button type="submit">Add a comment</button>
</form>
```

I have updated my app.routes like so:

```
app.route('/api/tasks/:taskId').all(tasksPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(tasks.read)
.put(tasks.update)
.delete(tasks.delete)
.put(tasks.newCo); // this is the new function I am trying to add
```

and tried to set up the functionality in my server.controller

```
exports.newCo = function(req, res) {
var task = req.task;
var task_id = req.task._id;
Task.findByIdAndUpdate(
task_id,
{ $push : { comments: req.task.comments }},
{ safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err, Task);
        }
        return res.json(Task);
    }
)
}
```

I don't quite understand how I communicate my client.controller with my server.controller to execute the function to update my task and push the comment into the array.

My latest attempt on client.controller was:

```
function newCo(isValid) {
        if (!isValid) {
            $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'vm.form.taskForm');
                return false;
        }
        if (vm.task._id) {
                vm.task.$newCo(successCallback, errorCallback);
            } else {
                vm.task.$save(successCallback, errorCallback);
            }

        function successCallback(res) {
                $state.go('tasks.view', {
                    taskId: res._id
                });
            }

            function errorCallback(res) {
                vm.error = res.data.message;
            }
    }
```

If anyone could please point me in the right direction I would be so, so grateful! Thank you all in advance!

**for example, this is how the remove() is working**

client.controller

```
// Remove existing Task
    function remove() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
                vm.task.$remove($state.go('tasks.list'));
            }
        }
```

server.controller

```
exports.delete = function(req, res) {
    var task = req.task;
    task.remove(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(task);
        }
    });
};
```

server.routes.js

```
  app.route('/api/tasks/:taskId').all(tasksPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(tasks.read)
    .put(tasks.update)
    **.delete(tasks.delete)**
```

and finally, html view:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="vm.remove()">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this process:

In html:

You don't need to pass `vm.form.taskForm.$valid` in `newCo` function can check from form. submit button can keep disable if form invalid `ng-disabled="vm.form.taskForm.$invalid"`. Also can use `ng-model="vm.task.newComment"` instead of `ng-model="vm.task.comments.comment"` because of you want to add new comment so no need to use `comments.comment`. so can use html like:

```
<form name="vm.form.taskForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="vm.newCo()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.task.newComment" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="ask a question about this task">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="vm.form.taskForm.$invalid">Add a comment</button>
</form>
```

and I guess you used `controller as` like `ng-controller="yourCtrl as vm"` or in route provider used like `controllerAs: 'vm'`

In your controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.task = task //predefined
vm.newCo = function() {
  // used $http.put('/api/tasks/21' according to your server side route
  $http.put('/api/tasks/21', {
    comment: vm.task.newComment;
  }).then(successCallback, errorCallback); //say 21 is taskId

  function successCallback(res) {
    $state.go('tasks.view', {
      taskId: res.data._id
    });
  }

  function errorCallback(res) {
    vm.error = res.data.message;
  }
};
```

Server side controller:

```
exports.newCo = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, 
    {
      "$push": {
        comments: req.body.comment
      }
    }, {
      new: true //to return updated document
    })
    .exec(function(error, task) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Failed to add comment due to invalid params!'});
      }
      return res.status(200).send(task);
    });
};
```

and in your schema should use `Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead of `Schema.ObjectId`

```
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

Comment: hey @shaishab roy thanks so much for your input. I have tried your suggestions however jshint is throwing some errors on running grunt. I was wondering if you have a suggestion for client side without $http.put('/api/tasks/21', { in the function. for example, the remove function I have added to my edit

Comment: ok, can you show your full controller and ui in plunker to better understand @loulala

Comment: I made a slight tweak to client controller and am now succesfully pushing into the array. thanks very much @shaishab

Comment: I tried to replicate the function for another form, however every time I press submit it pushes a null value to my comments array, rather than my new array. I have renamed the function and changed the variables for the client side controller and the req.body for the server side, do you have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: can you show your `$http.put(..` method  and how received in server side? @loulala

Comment: thanks so much for getting back to me. in the end I had to use a put request to get the function to work. here is copies of the current code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777769/angularjs-can-i-have-two-post-requests-resolving-to-same-api-endpoint

Comment: @ShaishabRoy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113867/how-to-store-table-with-particular-column-should-stored-in-array-and-retrieve-it