# angularjs - can I have two .post requests resolving to same api endpoint?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I apologise if this is a stupid question, please allow me to explain a little. I am running a MEAN application.

In the server routes for my CRUD generated module I have included **two separate post requests** to the same api end point.

```
app.route('/api/tasks/:taskId').all(tasksPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(tasks.read)
.put(tasks.update)
.delete(tasks.delete)
.post(tasks.newCo)
.post(tasks.newOffer);
```

Each of these perform a separate push request into my mongo document for task, based on the taskId.

When I run one function at a time, each individual function works successfully and pushes into the correct array.
However, when I run include both functions on the same page at the same time the newOffer function pushes a null value into the newCo array. And the newCo function continues to work successfully.

I have no idea why..

again, I apologise if this is a stupid question.

**server.controller.js**

```
/**
 * Add a new comment
 */
exports.newCo = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, 
    {
      "$push": {
        comments: req.body.comment
      }
    }, {
      new: true //to return updated document
    })
    .exec(function(error, task) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Failed to add comment due to invalid params!'});
      }
      return res.status(200).send(task);
    });
};

/**
 * Add a new offer
 */
exports.newOffer = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, 
    {
      "$push": {
        offers: req.body.offer
      }
    }, {
      new: true //to return updated document
    })
    .exec(function(error, task) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Failed to add offer due to invalid params!'});
      }
      return res.status(200).send(task);
    });
};
```

**client.controller.js**

```
vm.newCo = function() {
            $http.post('/api/tasks/' + task._id , {comment: { comment: vm.task.newComment, user: vm.authentication.user, profileImageURL: vm.authentication.user.profileImageURL, displayName: vm.authentication.user.displayName } })
            .then(successCallback, errorCallback); 

      function successCallback(res) {
        $state.transitionTo($state.current, $state.params, {
                    reload: true,
                    inherit: false,
                    notify: true
                });
      }

      function errorCallback(res) {
        vm.error = res.data.message;
      }
    };
        //close new comment function


    //new offer
        vm.newOffer = function() {
            $http.post('/api/tasks/' + task._id , {offer: { offerDesc: vm.task.offerDesc, offerPrice: vm.task.offerPrice, user: vm.authentication.user, profileImageURL: vm.authentication.user.profileImageURL, displayName: vm.authentication.user.displayName } })
            .then(successCallback, errorCallback); 
            alert('it worked!');
      function successCallback(res) {
        $state.transitionTo($state.current, $state.params, {
                    reload: true,
                    inherit: false,
                    notify: true
                });
      }

      function errorCallback(res) {
        vm.error = res.data.message;
      }
    };
         //close new offer function
```

Comment: I see two possible solutions.  1.  Make one endpoint and have it run multiple queries if needed (can be conditional based on the request object).  Then have that one endpoint return a response.  2.  Make first query from the client, on the response form that query, make a second query to the backend and pass the data needed from query 1.  All you would need to do is call query2 from the query1 returned promise.

Comment: If you're using RESTful api, then No. You should represent your resources differently, so that you won't run into this issue. This is more of a design issue.

Comment: @user2263572 thank you for your suggestions, I am going to try messing around with my api endpoints now or try a conditional request.

Comment: @jmugz3 thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you couldn't use same `api` for two `post` method. you can use different methods for same `api` like (`post, get, put, delete ...`) but not same method multiple time.

you should use different `api` for two `post` method .

like for task `api`

```
app.route('/api/tasks/:taskId').all(tasksPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(tasks.read)
.put(tasks.update)
.delete(tasks.delete)
.post(tasks.newCo);
```

for offer `api`

```
app.route('/api/offer/:taskId').all(tasksPolicy.isAllowed)
.post(tasks.newOffer);
```

if you use same `api` and two `post` method then always call first `post` method so second one always **unreachable**. When you call this `api` to add **offer** for that task then call `tasks.newCo` function and when you want receive `req.body.comment` get `null` or `undefined` so add `empty` or `null` **comment** but never will add **offer**.

Comment: thanks again @shaishabroy I am going to try messing around with my endpoints now and will let you know how I get on

Comment: okay, finally finished. I had to create new service and endpoint api/offers/:offerId which includes the :taskId, now I need to query to show offers with same taskId as current task page