# How to get the array value and in structurized using Mongoose?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mongojs

I am using **MeanStack AngularJS**. I stored the values into MongoDB like this:

### Data format

```
"RoleName" : "Verify",    
"IsActive" : true,
"UIList" : 
    {
        "UiName": "One",
        "View" : false,
        "Edit" : false
    },
    {
       "UiName": "Two",
        "View" : false,
        "Edit" : false
    },
    {
        "UiName": "Three",
        "View" : false,
        "Edit" : false
    },
    {
        "UiName": "Four",
        "View" : false,
        "Edit" : false
    },
    {
        "UiName": "Five",
        "View" : false,
        "Edit" : false
    }
```

### Contoller

```
$http.get('/Manage_Datashow').success(function (response) {
    $scope.Manage_Roleser = response;
});
```

### Server

```
app.get('/Manage_Datashow', function (req, res) {
    db.New_Role.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Here I attached my sample code. I want to bind the values in list using `ng-repeat`.

My code:

```
<ul ng-repeat=Manage_Rolese in Manage_Roleser >
  <li>{{Manage_Rolese.UIList.UiName}}</li>
  <li>{{Manage_Rolese.UIList.View}}</li>
  <li>{{Manage_Rolese.UIList.Edit}}</li>
</ul>
```

Example:

[image]

I need output like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div Class="container" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namesctrl">
  
  <table>
   <thead>
    <th>
     UiName
    </th>
    <th>
     View
    </th>
    <th>
     Edit
    </th>
   </thead>
   <tr ng-repeat="mgr in Manage_Roleser.UIList">
    <td>
     {{mgr.UiName}}
    </td>
    <td>
    |{{mgr.View}}
    </td>
    <td>
     {{mgr.View}}
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>  


 <script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

 <script>
  var app=angular.module("myapp", []);
  app.controller("namesctrl", function($scope){

   $scope.Manage_Roleser= 
   {
    "RoleName" : "Verify",    
       "IsActive" : true,
    "UIList": [{
    "UiName": "One",
    "View" : false,
    "Edit" : false
   },{
    "UiName": "Two",
    "View" : false,
    "Edit" : false
   },
   {
    "UiName": "Three",
    "View" : false,
    "Edit" : false
   },
   {
    "UiName": "Four",
    "View" : false,
    "Edit" : false
   },
   {
    "UiName": "Five",
    "View" : false,
    "Edit" : false
   }]
  }
   

  });



 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @saurabh pls verify my data 
 "RoleName" : "Verify",    
    "IsActive" : true, and third column is UIList inside UIList those data's are stored

Comment: Thanks for supporting

Comment: `UIList` will be an array. As I mentioned in my solution

Comment: i saw that but when i get values from db
 <tr ng-repeat="mgr in Manage_Roleser[0].UIList">
then only works

Comment: i don't know y it's need [0]

Comment: yeah depend on if `Manage_Roleser` is an object or array. Happy to help you

Comment: Accept my answer if it works for you :)
and mark it upword :)

Comment: whether i want to update the particular view edit option means how query look's help to write update query for that

Comment: Yeah Man that's rigth

Answer (score 2):

First off all you json is not a valid one please check that and go through the below snippest

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Manage_Roleser =[ {
    "RoleName" : "Verify",    
    "IsActive" : true,
    "UIList" : [{
            "UiName": "One",
            "View" : false,
            "Edit" : false
        },
        {
           "UiName": "Two",
            "View" : false,
            "Edit" : false
        },
          {
            "UiName": "Three",
            "View" : false,
            "Edit" : false
        },
         {
            "UiName": "Four",
            "View" : false,
            "Edit" : false
        },
          {
            "UiName": "Five",
            "View" : false,
            "Edit" : false
        }]
       } ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 
 <div>
  
     <div  ng-repeat="i in Manage_Roleser[0].UIList">
       {{i.UiName}} | {{i.View}}   {{i.Edit}}
      
       
     </div>
   
 </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Add your headings like as you want.

Comment: whether i want to update the particular view edit option means how query look's help to write update query for that