# Update table Array Values in mongoose or mongojs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

i using mean stack angularjs i stored the values into db like

## Format

```
{
      "RoleName" : "Verify",    
        "IsActive" : true,
        "UIList" : [{
                "UiName": "One",
                "View" : false,
                "Edit" : false
            },{
               "UiName": "Two",
                "View" : false,
                "Edit" : false
            },
              {
                "UiName": "Three",
                "View" : false,
                "Edit" : false
            },
             {
                "UiName": "Four",
                "View" : false,
                "Edit" : false
            },
              {
                "UiName": "Five",
                "View" : false,
                "Edit" : false
            }]

}
```

Now i want to update the UILits UIName=Three and view and also i try update query to update the values but it's won't work anyone help how to solve this

## server

```
var id = req.params.id;
var View = 'true';
var Edit = 'true';
 
 db.New_Role.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) },
        update: { $set:   {"UIList.View":View,"UIList.Edit":Edit }   },
        new: true
    }
```

Comment: check this function for mongoose: [updateMany](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany)

Comment: embedded @ chridam now check i change my json

Comment: @Sadok Mtir that's wrong man i am new in mongoose try to modify it

Comment: @jose as chridam said, before all this is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @sadok now check yar

Comment: i think this format will stored in my db i verify it